# Dynamically Change a Stores Model in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

Is it possible to dynamically change a JsonStore's model in Sencha Touch, I've tried insert() and add() but those seem to pertain to adding records to the store, not changing the model reference.

I'm using the 1.0 release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't, just create a new store. Note that if you're changing the model it's entirely possible you want a new proxy as well anyway.